# How to get a specific number from a list?

Tags: random, python-3.7

I want to randomize the words in the list and if the randomized word equals to scissor I want the game to tell me that I've won but I cant find the solution, could you tell me where I done wrong?

I have tried "if 3 in my_list:" but still can't find the solution

```
import random

my_list = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
random.choice(my_list)
print(random.choice(my_list))

if random.choice(my_list) == my_list[3]:
    print("You Won!")
else:
    print("You Lost!")
```

I want to print "You Won" when the random.choice is scissors in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should get this error ***IndexError: list index out of range***
because *my_list* have total 3 items,

> my_list[0] -> "rock"
>
> my_list[1] -> "paper"
>
> my_list[2] -"scissor"

so result of random.choice from `my_list` always will be  `my_list[0`] or `my_list[1]` or `my_list[2]`

In this line `if random.choice(my_list) == my_list[3]:` checking if value of `random.choice()` is equal to `my_list[3]` but theres no item in 3rd position of ur list.

"scissor" position in `my_list[2]`. 
so this should work,

```
import random
my_list = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
rand_item = random.choice(my_list)

if rand_item == my_list[2]:
    print("You Won!")
else:
    print("You Lost!")
```